# Array indexing does not work for the node label

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrays

There is something I cannot understand. I'm using array indexing and it works for determining the radius of the circles and to positioning the nodes. However it does not work as the node content.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\radi{{1,2,3,4}}
\foreach \x/\a [count=\n] in {0/15,1/345,2/345,3/345}
    \draw[very thin, draw=red!50!white] (0,0) circle [radius={\radi[\x]}] node at (\a:{\radi[\x]}) {{\radi[\x]}};


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use simply `{\n}` as label?

Comment: ups, I did not realized that would be a solution in the Minimal Working Example (MWE) I prepared. In my real situation I do need to access the vector.

Comment: If you need to count the items in the list, you may want to use the `count` option of the `foreach` loop.

Comment: The node content is not a TikZ/pgf formula. You may use `\pgfmathparse{...}` then `\pgfmathresult`...

Comment: The solutions offered here work only for numeric arrays. To anybody from the future, if you are looking for a way to index an array for arbitrary content, see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/551501/69346

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please don't use `color` with TikZ!! It already loads `xcolor`.

Paul Gaborit already gave you the answer that a brace pair doesn't necessarily mean a math operation. Here it is just put inside a text box and TikZ doesn't evaluate it. You can either go parsing the math inside a `\pgfextra{...}` and use `\pgfmathresult` or you can explicitly define more variables that use the loop variable via `evaluate` key.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\radi{{1,2,3,4}}
\foreach \x/\a [
    count=\n,
    evaluate=\x as \myvar using ({\radi[\x]})
    ] in {0/15,1/345,2/345,3/345}
    \draw[very thin, draw=red!50!white] 
        (0,0) circle [radius={\myvar}] 
        node at (\a:{\radi[\x]}) {\myvar};


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I followed a similar approach, but instead used `\pgfmathsetmacro\result{\myarray[\i]}`, I learned about that here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/337831/pgfmathparse-basic-usage