# pgfmathparse basic usage

Tags: pgfmathparse

Please, what I'm doing wrong in this test:

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfmathparse{10*2}
\node at (4,-5) {$2 \cdot 10 = \pgfmathresult$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It gives as output a line:

```
2 * 10 = -5.0
```

instead of:

```
2 * 10 = 20
```

?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`\pgfmathresult` holds the result of the last computation done by pgfmath; in this case this was the evaluation of the y-coordinate of `(4,-5)`, which happens to be -5. Use `\pgfmathsetmacro` to assign the result to a macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\result{10*2}
  \node at (4,-5) {$2 \cdot 10 = \result$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To obtain an integer value, use `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` instead of `\pgfmathsetmacro`. For more information see the [TikZ manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf); in version 3.0.1a this topic is presented in section 89 on page 923.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro\result{10*2}
  \node at (4,-5) {$2 \cdot 10 = \result$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Any way to produce integer result instead of real number?

Comment: @pasabaporaqui See the updated answer.

Answer (score 13):

[`tikz`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) performs some calculations when using `\node`s. These calculations are done using `\pgfmathparse`. As such, your `\pgfmathresult` is overwritten with something else.

Instead, place the `\pgfmathparse` immediately before `\pgfmathresult`, or store `\pgfmathresult` immediately after evaluating it for use later:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfmathparse{10*2}\edef\storeresult{\pgfmathresult}%
  \node at (4,-5) {$2 \cdot 10 = \pgfmathprintnumber\storeresult$};
  \node at (4,-6) {$2 \cdot 10 = \pgfmathparse{10*2}\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfmathresult$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```