# Why can \pgfmathtruncatemacro not be a label?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath

I'm trying to use pgfmath to calculate a modular value. However, when I try to give this value as a label to a node, it does not compile.

The following code fails:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    \pgfmathsetmacro{\N}{5}

    \foreach \x in {0,...,\N}
    {
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\next}{Mod(\x+1,\N)}
        \node at (\next,0) {\next};
%        \node at (\next,0) {\x};
    }

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

It gives the error: "Missing } inserted.  } l.16 }". Line 16 is the line with the "}".

The code where I replace the line with "\node" with the line that was commented out, it does compile (as an example). Could someone please explain what is going wrong, and how I can fix it?

I tried to do what is done in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/337831/pgfmathparse-basic-usage), but math mode doesn't seem to help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `\next`, since it's special. It's used throughout the kernel and could be redefined, leading to the issue you're experiencing. Instead, use something more descriptive like `\nextnode`.

Comment: It is in `pgfrcs.code.tex` line 67-73. The weird thing is that PGF usually protects its `next`, such as `\@next` in `tikz.code.tex`.

Comment: @Symbol1 That's the TeX primitive `\next` for plain TeX compatibility looking for package input before loading anything yet.

Comment: @percusse really? I think I need a reference.

Comment: @Symbol1: When you use `\nextnode` and add `\tracingmacros1` (even inside a group) around the `\node` part and then view your `.log`, you'll see some reference to `\next` that still exists.

Comment: @Werner I saw two `\next` that come from `tikz.code.tex`. So my previous comment is totally wrong.

Comment: OK I get it. The `\next` is probably used to absorb the `{` in the construction `\node{text};`.

Answer (score 1):

When Ti*k*Z process your node, it uses

```
\let\next=
```

to absorb the begin-group character `{` in your code

> ```
> \node at (\next,0) {\next};
> ```

Therefore `\next` will be `Mod(\x+1,\N)` until Ti*k*Z enters the node.

That is the reason why you can use `\next` in the coordinate

> ```
> \node at (\next,0) {\x};
> ```

but cannot use it in a node.