# define variables using calculations

Tags: macros

How can I define a variable, which is calculated from different variables, something like this:

```
\newcommand \varA {3}
\newcommand \varB {2}
\newcommand \varC {\varB*\varA}
```

So that `\varC` will conain `6` and not `3*2`. This is important, since `\varC` will be used as a variable in text and in a pgfplot.

Comment: Use `\pgfmathparse`. Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/337831/pgfmathparse-basic-usage

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pgfmathparse basic usage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/337831/pgfmathparse-basic-usage)

Comment: I don't think so. Because I need the variable also in outside of a pgfplot. And it doesn't seem to work there

Comment: Oh I figured it out, it does work. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your aim is to use floating point numbers, `pgfmath` is not good. Look at the following example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfp}
\usepackage{pgfmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\setvar}{mm}
 {
  \fp_zero_new:c { l_flobue_var_#1_fp }
  \fp_set:cn { l_flobue_var_#1_fp } { #2 }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\usevar}{m}
 {
  \fp_use:c { l_flobue_var_#1_fp }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section{PGF}

\pgfmathsetmacro\varA{123.45}
\pgfmathsetmacro\varB{0.012345}
\pgfmathsetmacro\varC{\varA/\varB}

\verb|\varA| is \varA \\
\verb|\varB| is \varB \\
\verb|\varC| is \varC

\section{xfp}

\setvar{A}{123.45}
\setvar{B}{0.012345}
\setvar{C}{\usevar{A}/\usevar{B}}

\verb|A| is \usevar{A} \\
\verb|B| is \usevar{B} \\
\verb|C| is \usevar{C}

\setvar{B}{0.0012345}
\setvar{C}{\usevar{A}/\usevar{B}}

\noindent
Now \verb|C| is \usevar{C}; try with pgfmath

\end{document}
```

[image]

There are several advantages in the `xfp` approach with `\setvar` and `\usevar`:

1. greater accuracy
2. larger range
3. no `\pgfmathsetmacro` that does no check about the command being defined
4. greater flexibility

The fourth point is worth an example: if you need to use the result of the previous division, you can simply do

```
\fpeval{\usevar{A}/\usevar{B}}
```

and don't need to set another variable for getting the result *expandably*.